# How to increase the hard disk space of thin provisioning vm

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, vmware, centos7

Created thin provisioning vm(centos 7) with 50 GB hard disk. But it doesnt automatically increase the space when there is a need. Can someone please tell how to increase the space of "/" directory.

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   14G   14G   16K 100% /
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G  912M  985M  49% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  147M  351M  30% /boot
tmpfs                    380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                    380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/1002
```

Below are the output of pvs command.

```
[root@inches-rmdev01 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  15.51g 40.00m
```

Below are the output of vgs command.

```
[root@inches-rmdev01 ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  centos   1   2   0 wz--n- 15.51g 40.00m
```

Below are the output of lvs command.

```
[root@inches-rmdev01 ~]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root centos -wi-ao---- 13.87g
  swap centos -wi-ao----  1.60g
```

Below are the output of fdisk command.

```
[root@inches-rmdev01 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0009a61a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    33554431    16264192   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        33554432   104857599    35651584   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 14.9 GB, 14889779200 bytes, 29081600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 1719 MB, 1719664640 bytes, 3358720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `fdisk -l` output you can see that you have a 35GB disk `/dev/sda3`. To extend your root volume you can add this disk to LVM (Logical Volume Manager):

`pvcreate /dev/sda3`

This will add the unused disk `/dev/sda3` as a new pv (physical volume) to LVM.
Next step is to extend your root vg (volumegroup). In your case it is easy since you've got only one vg:

`vgextend centos /dev/sda3`

Now you have added the 35GB disk to your vg and you can distribute it to your lv's (logical volume).

Finaly you can add as much space as you need (up to 35GB) to your root-volume with the `lvextend` command:

If you want to use the whole 35GB you can use:
`lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/centos-root`

If you only want to add a certain ammount (i.e 1G) you can use this:
`lvextend -L +1G /dev/mapper/centos-root`

And finaly resize your filesystem:

`resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root`

The LVM logic is:
1. Harddisk `fdisk -l`
2. Physical Volume `pvs`
3. Volume Group `vgs`
4. Logical Volume `lvs`

Comment: If you provide me with the output of `pvs vgs lvs` and which size your / sould be I can improve my answer.

Comment: and the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Edited the question with output of pvs, vgs, lvs, fdisk -l as you asked.

Comment: Hi. I hope this will help. Regards

Comment: Except resize2fs all other commands worked fine. Since centos7 used xfs as default file system, giving the command "xfs_growfs  /dev/mapper/centos-root" worked.